# Change get_post_thumb responsively?

Tags: post-thumbnails, responsive

How can I responsively change the get_post_thumb when reaching a certain breakpoint with PHP code?

I use the following code to print my posts thumb at the moment:

```
<?php 
echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; 
the_post_thumbnail('featured-cat',array('title' => '')); 
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Which are specified in my `functions.php` file:

```
add_image_size( 'featured-cat', 248, 110, true ); //featured-cat
```

What I then want to do is to instead use the following code when reaching 320px in screen size. I want to use

```
add_image_size( '**featured-cat-mobile**', 200, 80, true ); //featured-cat mobile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using conditionals for mobile ie: **[wp_is_mobile()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile)**

Define both the sizes like

```
add_image_size( 'featured-cat', 248, 110, true ); //featured-cat
add_image_size( 'featured-cat-mobile', 200, 80, true ); //featured-cat mobile
```

and edit the code like the below:--

```
<?php 
echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">';
if( wp_is_mobile() )
    the_post_thumbnail('featured-cat-mobile',array('title' => ''));
else
    the_post_thumbnail('featured-cat',array('title' => '')); 
echo '</div>';
?>
```